# [JavaScript][API] Unable to pass body when sending request to API via fetch

Tags: javascript, python, fetch-api

I have created an API written in Python using flask. This API accepts request with parameters in 'POST' method and returns a JSON as the response. Now I am creating a JavaScript program that sends request to the API. I am using 'fetch' to send the request to the API, but unable to pass the body parameters when sending the request. The following is my code in JavaScript program.

```
call_api = async (event) => {
    const fetch = require("node-fetch");

    const api_url = 'http://000.0.0.0:0000/doc';

    const params = {
        key: '873s592f',
        uid: '10'
    };

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        body: params
    };

    fetch (api_url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.msg);
        });
}
```

An expected request would be `http://000.0.0.0:0000/doc?key=873s592f&uid=10`, but the program is sending `http://000.0.0.0:0000/doc` itself. Sending the request to API using Postman works, so I do not believe the API has fundamental errors.

I checked my API and it keeps getting a request without any body (or params). It gets the request as 'POST' method, though. For `body: params` part, I have tried
`body: JSON.stringify(params)`
`body: "key=873s592f&uid=10"`
and other forms already, but none of them works.

I have also tried `'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` instead of `'Content-Type':'application/json'`.

Any advice for passing the body to the API request will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think the problem is on the client side?

Comment: @jabaa I thought so, because the API returns a proper response when calling it on Postman. Do you think that there is a problem in the server side? I am very new to both API and JavaScript.

Comment: `?key=873s592f&uid=10` are query parameters, not body parameters. Body parameters are in the message body and can't be seen in the request URL or header.

Comment: @jabaa Shoot you are right. I will go search for ways to send query parameters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't find an option for query parameters in `node-fetch`. Looks like you have to build the URL with `Object.entries(params).map(param => \`${param[0]}=${param[1]}\`).join('&')`.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vGLs4PdZHmS25Uez

Comment: @jabaa That is exactly what I needed. Thanks mate!